# When training model it prints epoch 1/2 then cell just shuts down and all variables are lost (using IBM lab)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, ibm-cloud, lstm

When trying to train my LSTM model my cell will print out epoch 1/2 training on n samples etc and then just shut down and all variables are lost therefore I have to run all the cells again. I have attached images of the part of code where I built the model and what happens when trying to train the model, any help would be great!
I had read up somewhere that this code might help - below the one to do with os(don't know what It does) but it didn't change anything

```
import os

os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] = 'True'
```

Below is my code excluding the data cleaning etc..

[Image of libraries imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7o72.png) (code is below this link)

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==2.0

!pip install plotly
!pip install --upgrade nbformat
!pip install nltk
!pip install spacy # spaCy is an open-source software library for advanced natural language processing
!pip install WordCloud
!pip install gensim # Gensim is an open-source library for unsupervised topic modeling and natural language processing
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import nltk
import re
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
import gensim
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.parsing.preprocessing import STOPWORDS
# import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot, Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Embedding, Input, LSTM, Conv1D, MaxPool1D, Bidirectional, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

nltk.download("stopwords")
```

[Image of Tokenization and padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P5nM.png) (code below)

```
# split data into test and train 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.clean_joined, df.label, test_size = 0.20)

from nltk import word_tokenize

# Create a tokenizer to tokenize the words and create sequences of tokenized words
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = total_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)
train_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)
test_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)


embedding_dim = 100
embeddings_index = dict()

f = open('glove.6B.100d.txt')
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_index[word] = coefs
f.close()
print(f'Found {len(embeddings_index)} word vectors')

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((total_words, embedding_dim))
for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
    if index > total_words -1:
        break
    else:
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            embedding_matrix[index] = embedding_vector

padded_train = pad_sequences(train_sequences,maxlen = 16274, padding = 'post', truncating = 'post')
padded_test = pad_sequences(test_sequences,maxlen = 16274, truncating = 'post')
```

[Image of Building model and model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzMbR.png) (code below)

```
# Sequential Model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(total_words, embedding_dim,
                    embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
                    trainable=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Bi-Directional RNN and LSTM
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128)))

# Dense layers
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation= 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()


Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, None, 100)         17437200  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, None, 100)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 256)               234496    
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,704,721
Trainable params: 267,521
Non-trainable params: 17,437,200
____________________________________
```

[Image on what happens when I try train model - notice the cell shuts off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsHDT.png) (code below)

```
y_train = np.asarray(y_train)

# train the model
model.fit(padded_train, y_train, batch_size = 64, validation_split = 0.1, epochs = 2, verbose=2)
```

might be helpful to view image here but essentially this gets printed and cell is shut off

'Train on 14947 samples, validate on 1661 samples
Epoch 1/2'

Any help would be great!

Comment: My best guess is that the process is taking too much RAM and is killed by the OS. Try to reduce your batch size, and see if the error happens again.

Comment: @Lescurel same result.. (used 32 as batch size)... could it be because of my padding being the length of the largest word or my max features size being the number of total words...? Would it help if I shared the whole notebook?.. sorry to bother you again.

Comment: Did you try with the batch size of 1? If this indeed a RAM issue, maybe you could try to decrease your padding. Make sure that your inputs still make sense.

Comment: @Lescurel ok will do.. what would be an ideal padding length? it is currently 16274 (which is max number of words in any document)